# Finding the order of 3 modulo 242

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know from Euler's theorem that
\begin{equation*}
3^{110} \equiv 1\mod 242 
\end{equation*}
because
\begin{equation*}
\phi(242) = 110.
\end{equation*}
However to find the order of $3$, I need to find a minimal $n$ such that:
\begin{equation*}
3^{n} \equiv 1\mod 242. 
\end{equation*}
[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(3%5en)+mod+242+%3d+1) says that it's $5$. How can I compute it manually, i.e. on paper?

Comment: Hint: do you know the small powers of $3$?

Comment: Further hint: the order will be a factor of $110=2\times 5\times 11$ so you only have a few possibilities you need to check.

Comment: Start with $x=1$. Repeat the process of $x=3x\bmod{242}$ until you get $x=1$, and count the total number of iterations.

Comment: @MarkBennet So, the only solution is to bruteforce all factorization combinations, i.e. $6$ options? Also, if $2$ and $5$ wouldn't work, proceeding with $11$ and above becomes less trivial on paper.

Comment: It must be true what Wolfram says and verify it is quite immediate

Comment: @Paul $3^{11}=(3^5)^2\times 3$ and you can always reduce by the modulus at any stage to simplify the arithmetic. Repeated squaring is often a way to simplify the computation of powers.

Comment: @MarkBennet thank you for your help. You can post an answer if you want, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

we have $$3^1=3,3^2=9,3^3=27,3^4=81,3^5=243$$